# Finding the actual type in macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I am trying to write a macro that extracts the type information. Here is a minimized version.

```
class Extractor[E] {
  def extract(entity: E): Unit = macro ExtractorImpl.extractImpl[E]
}

object ExtractorImpl {
  def extractImpl[E: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(entity: c.Expr[E]): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val actualType = implicitly[WeakTypeTag[E]].tpe
    c.info(c.enclosingPosition, actualType.toString, true)

    q"{}"
  }
}
```

Here is a typical implementation of `Extractor`:

```
case class Person(name: String)
object PersonExtractor extends Extractor[Person]
```

If I use this class directly as in `PersonExtractor.extract(new Person("test name"))`, I get `Person` printed as info. But, if I use it indirectly as follows, it prints only `E`:

```
class Mapper[E](extractor: Extractor[E]) {
  def extract(e: E) = extractor.extract(e)
}

class PersonMapper extends Mapper[Person](new Extractor[Person])

class Test {
  new PersonMapper().extract(new Person("test name"))
}
```

How do I go about getting the `Person` type available as `actualType`?

Comment: try use it `val actualType: c.universe.Type = c.weakTypeOf[E].typeSymbol.asClass.toType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use implicit macro

```
trait Extractor[E] {
  def extract(entity: E): Unit
}

object Extractor {
  implicit def i[E] : Extractor[E] = macro ExtractorImpl.extractImpl[E]
}

object ExtractorImpl {
  def extractImpl[E: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context):c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val actualType = c.weakTypeOf[E]
    c.info(c.enclosingPosition, actualType.toString, false)

      q"""
        new Extractor[$actualType]{
          def extract(entity: $actualType): Unit = println("hello world")
        }
      """
  }
}
```

// test

```
case class Person(name: String)

//object PersonExtractor extends Extractor[Person]

class Mapper[E] {
  def extract(e: E)(implicit extractor: Extractor[E]) = extractor.extract(e)
}

class PersonMapper extends Mapper[Person]

class Test {
  new PersonMapper().extract(new Person("test name")) // show info:Person 
}
```

Edit:
//test2

```
class Mapper2[E](extractor: Extractor[E]) {
  def extract(e: E) = extractor.extract(e)
}

object Mapper2 extends Mapper2[Person](Extractor.i[Person])//also  show info:Person
```